# SQL crawler with ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server

Curious if anyone can provide some guidance on how to setup this SQL query. I have an ERP database, and there are many transaction records. If an item has a certain type of transaction type, "BOM Issue", it is logged with a unique transaction ID. Ex. 12345. Transaction ID's are logged sequentially. So the next transaction will be 12346. If I search for a part, and it finds that this item has had a BOM Issue transaction. I want my SQL query to start at it's transaction ID and crawl through these transaction records by decrementing the transaction ID. It must crawl through sequentially until it reaches a transaction record for a part which has a transaction type of "BOM receipt".

Here is a visual. I search for the yellow part, and want the results of the green part.

[image]

Comment: So the query is just to return the first BOM Receipt prior to the BOM Issue? If not then you need to explain what the relationship is between 'Child Part 10' and 'Parent Part'.

Comment: Why must it crawl sequentially?  Sequential / iterative operations are anti-patterns in a relational db system.

Comment: @DeanOC yes, exactly that.

Comment: @squillman It doesn't necessarily need to crawl sequentially, I am just presuming that it does. I need the first BOM receipt prior to the BOM Issue. The transaction ID's are handed out sequentially after the first BOM receipt, and my part in question can fall anywhere inside the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM transactions WHERE type = 'BOM receipt' AND id < 12345
```

*Edit (answering the comment):*

Well, you simply might want to iterate over all the ids in the application layer and use above query...

A SQL solution for:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions t1, transactions t2
    WHERE t1.type = 'BOM receipt' AND t2.type = 'BOM Issue'
    AND t2.id > t1.id
    AND (
        t2.id < (
            SELECT MIN(id) FROM transactions
            WHERE type = 'BOM receipt' AND id > t1.id)
        OR NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT id FROM transactions
            WHERE type = 'BOM receipt' AND id > t1.id)
    )
```

This selects the receipt for any issue. You might want to only select specific columns (e. g. `t1.id, t2.id`), and you can add additional conditions: `AND t2.id = firstWantedId AND t2.id = secondWantedId` for only getting the ids you are interested in and if you need the resulted sorted, add `ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id`.

There is possibly yet potential to optimise, but at least it works...

Comment: Isn't specifying id < 1235 a little too specific? I'm guessing the OP is after a more generic solution.

Comment: I assumed that the id is known to the OP for whatever reason and he can replace it appropriately (e. g. a prepared statement with `AND id < ?` in the application layer).

Comment: @Aconcagua hmmmm....this is interesting. I'll need to test this out tomorrow (already at home). If you are familiar with manufacturing, there will be many BOM receipts, and in searching for a part, it will also have many instances of BOM issue (across different timestamps). How would I modify this to be a little more dynamic? Say for example, the part I searched, had 5 instances at random ID's.